# How to to delete a duplicate data with the latest time submission from a database?

Tags: jquery, python, database, django

I am using the following query to obtain company from a database:

```
companies = Company.objects.order_by('submit_time').reverse()
```

The output I get:

2013-11-13 12:25:30+00:00  <--- delete

2013-11-13 12:25:30+00:00  <--- keep

2013-11-13 12:25:14+00:00  <--- keep

2013-11-13 12:25:13+00:00  <--- delete

2013-11-13 12:25:13+00:00  <--- keep

2013-11-13 05:11:55+00:00  <--- delete

2013-11-13 05:11:55+00:00  <--- keep

2013-11-13 05:11:29+00:00  <--- delete

2013-11-13 05:11:29+00:00  <--- keep

2013-11-13 05:11:28+00:00  <--- keep

The company submit time contains duplicates. I am using the code to find companies submitted at the same time:

```
seen = set()
result = []
for item in companies:
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item.submit_time)
        result.append(item.submit_time)
```

What would be a way to adjust the following code so I could find the duplicate company time submission and delete the company with the latest time and keep the company with the earlier time? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the "Delete company with the latest time and keep the earlier" bit when the duplication is the time itself. ie no earlier or later

couldn't you just:

```
seen = set()
result = []
for item in companies:
    if item.submit_time not in seen:
        seen.add(item.submit_time)
        result.append(item.submit_time)
    else:
        item.delete()
```

update:

```
seen = {}
result = []
for item in companies:
    if item.submit_time not in seen:
        seen[item.submit_time] = item
        result.append(item.submit_time)
    else:
        seen[item.submit_time].delete()
        seen[item.submit_time] = item
```

Comment: looking at your edit this would delete the second one you get to, but if the original query was in id asc order then the later id of the same time would be the one to be removed

Comment: just tested it out, it does it but the other way around
2013-11-13 12:25:30+00:00 <--- keep
2013-11-13 12:25:30+00:00 <--- delete
Instead of:
2013-11-13 12:25:30+00:00 <--- delete
2013-11-13 12:25:30+00:00 <--- keep
I need to keep it particularly in that order.

Comment: updated, not tested... should do what you want though